# How to write std::function for variable arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions, std-function, stdbind

I want to pass `std::function` as a callback parameter to another function.
The function to be bound is a static function with variable argument list.

The static function is as follows:

```
void abc::static_func(const char* const text,...);
```

`abc` is a static class and `static_func` is a static function.

The function where `std::function` parameter to be received:

```
void xyz(std::function<void(const CHAR* const text, ...)> arg);
```

I tried following:

```
std::function<void(const CHAR* const text, ...)> callback = std::bind(void(*)(const CHAR* const text, ...))(&abc::func);
```

I do not want to add auto as callback has to be passed to xyz function further.

I have looked up over online and I got a variadic template related answers but they do not fit into the above problem and mostly auto is used in all the answers.

Any suggestions/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `...` in your code a C vararg list?

Comment: If so, then just use a pointer to function.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki - I am using it in a cpp file. Are you suggesting me to use a function pointer instead of C++ std::function? There is no way to use std::function for a variable arg list?

Comment: @t.niese -  I looked into the answer, and I did not find how binding works for variable args. It is more specific to prinft and vprintf.

Comment: There's no any binding in your example.

Comment: Which arguments are you trying to bind ?

Comment: @madhurahegde the linked question, uses `prinft` as example, but it applies to all C vararg list.  `std::function<void(const CHAR* const text, ...)>` is not valid it has to be `std::function<void(const CHAR* const, va_list)>`, (as described in the duplicate)  and if you want to call that `std::function` with a variable number of arguments you would do that as described in the duplicate. Direct binding of arguments is not possible, you need to use indirection.

Comment: @t.niese Thank you, it worked. When you emphasized that binding is not possible, it clicked me :)